# Using reactiveFileReader function in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I would like your help to access the result elements that the reactiveFileReader function offers me, in which case the result is `fileData ()`

The server code is this:

```
    server <- function(input, output,session) {

        fileData <- reactiveFileReader(1000,session,filePath = 'ddeLink.xlsm', readFunc = read_excel)

        output$data <- renderTable({
            fileData()
        })
}
```

The excel spreadsheet `linkdde.xslm` every five minutes updates. It is composed of 2 columns where only column b is updated. The excel file bellow:

[image]

The code works fine. That is, whenever the excel spreadsheet updates my app Shiny also updates the mmatrix above, which is the `fileData ()`result.

The `fileData()`is always updating. The `fileData()` is the matrix above.

But my question is: How do I access the values ​​of this mtrix, represented by the `fileData ()` to create a plot that would be updated because the `fileData ()` is updating. In other words I want to have a plot updating every 5 minutes using the 5 minutes `fileData ()` matrix?

I did this:

```
output$data <- renderPlot({
 df<-as.data.frame(fileData())
 plot(df[,1])
})
```

But it didnt work.

Any help guys

Many thanks

Comment: what exactly didn't work? if you received an error `invalid quartz device size` then try using `plotOutput` instead of `uiOutput` in your ui (or edit your question and include ui). did you want to plot your numbers in the second column? that would be `plot(df[,2])` - if this doesn't help, please provide your full shiny code.

Comment: @Ben When I said that the code works fine I meant that it updates whenever the excel spreadsheet updates. Next I would like to plot on top of this matrix so that after the excel matrix was updated the plot was automatically updated. This is my idea. The `df`matrix is always updating, then I want to plot thet `df[,2]`column. And then I will have a updating plot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below example seems to work, where the plot is updated when the Excel file is updated. Is this what you are looking for? If not, please describe further what you need.

```
library(shiny)
library(readxl)

ui <- fluidPage(
  mainPanel(
    uiOutput("data"),
    plotOutput("plot")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output,session) {
  fileData <- reactiveFileReader(1000,
                                 session,
                                 filePath = 'ddeLink.xlsx', 
                                 readFunc = read_excel)

  output$data <- renderTable({
    fileData()
  })

  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    df<-as.data.frame(fileData())
    plot(df[,2]) 
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: perfect! I will edit and improve my question. Cuase this could be very helpful for other people. Many thanks for your time!

Comment: @Ben Is there a way to hide the data and just show the plot?

Comment: @Linkman you could change `renderTable` with `renderUI`. It works here.

Comment: To just show the plot (without table), remove `uiOutput("data")` from the `ui` --- and in that case, you won't need `output$data <- renderTable({fileData()})` either