# How to display live poll results using R Shiny dashboard

Tags: r, shiny, google-forms

I apologize for a very novice question.

I'm learning to use R shiny dashboard to display live infographics of polls performed through google forms.

This is the trial form: https://forms.gle/pixQ2pui5Qmgh9A4A
And this is the url that may be used to extract the .csv output of its responses:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1yS1l3Scvw98ueg5ZZe4021a3y5gMqe6FOP-ZrQIvHBo/export?format=csv&id=1yS1l3Scvw98ueg5ZZe4021a3y5gMqe6FOP-ZrQIvHBo&gid=1120079968

I understand that the reactiveFileReader() function should update the data continuously, but this does not seem to work, and the plot does not get updated unless the page is refreshed manually. How can the data be made to update itself continuously instead?

Thanks all!

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

 ui <- shinyUI(
  dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(title = "Data streaming"),
    dashboardSidebar(
      menuItem("Plot")
    ),
    dashboardBody(
      fluidRow(
        box(plotOutput("histogram"))
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- 
  shinyServer(function(input, output, session){

       form.url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1yS1l3Scvw98ueg5ZZe4021a3y5gMqe6FOP-ZrQIvHBo/export?format=csv&id=1yS1l3Scvw98ueg5ZZe4021a3y5gMqe6FOP-ZrQIvHBo&gid=1120079968"

      dat <- reactiveFileReader(1000, 
                                session, 
                                filePath=form.url, 
                                readFunc = function(filePath) {
                                  read.csv(url(filePath))
                                  })
      output$histogram <- renderPlot({
        hist(dat()$N, cex.main="", xlab="Poll", breaks=5)
        })
})

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Have you seen this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58774758/using-reactivefilereader-function-in-shiny

Comment: yes i have. but the only difference seems to be the line where the reactiveFileReader object is coerced into a data.frame. does that change it? either way I tried doing that as well and the result is the same. the plot can be displayed but it only updates itself when the refresh button is clicked

Answer (score 0):

[formr](https://formr.org/) is a free solution to live poll visualisation with R. They can host your polls but you can also host your own.

Comment: Added here because there is no answer to "live poll visualisation in R" throughout the SE network and this is the closest to it.